Octave for/while loop to determine all possible variable combinations with a set condition
I have 3 variables v1, v2 and v3 equal to 1. So v1 + v2 + v3 = 1. I'm trying to get every possible combination of these three variables with increments of 0.1 via looping in Octave. I'm not aware of any advanced commands or tools so I just used the basics of C++ that we've been taught in one of our classes.
v1 = 1;
v2 = 0;
v3 = 0;
        while (v2 < 1)
        v3 = 0;
        v4 = v2;
          for v3 = 0:0.1:v4
          varsum = v1 + v2 + v3;
          data(1,n) = v1;
          data(2,n) = v2;
          data(3,n) = v3;
          data(4,n) = varsum;
          v2 -= 0.1;
          n+=1
          endfor
        v1 -= 0.1;
        v2 = 1 - v1;
        endwhile

My expected results would look like this:
v1 v2 v3
10  0  0
 9  1  0
 9  0  1
 8  2  0
 :  :  :
 0  2  8
 0  1  9
 0  0 10

I know it's crude, I just programmed it the way I would've done it manually. I know there are 66 combinations in total, but I only get 65.
When checking the results, I found that it skips the
9 0 1
result and goes straight to
8 2 0
Everything else looks fine. I've had issues before with variable/s refusing to get 0 value so I'm afraid to modify it further out of fear I'll make it worse. How do I modify the code to not skip that one combination?

I would use two nested for loops. One is v1=0:0.1:1, and the other is v2=0:0.1:1-v1. Then you compute v3=1-v1-v2. You cannot skip anything that way.

Thanks for replying. That certainly looks like a better way to do it. I've switched everything into nested for loops and it runs better, also looks less cluttered. However, this time it skipped the 9 0 1 result. I tried moving everything by a decimal to the right and it gave the correct results. The problem may have been in how numbers are rounded up in octave. So I kept the whole number definitions on the loop (v1 = 0:1:10), divide it by 10 before collecting/applying the result, then multiplying it again by 10 after. It has worked well so far.

Yes, it is better to loop over integers. But why are you multiplying by 10? Are you rounding the result? Why do you need to produce intermediate results in the range 0.0-1.0 then? Why not directly produce the final results in the range 0-10?

My bad, I made a mistake on the expected results above. I actually needed them to fit the v1+v2+v3=1 constraint so my expected results should instead look like:
[v1,v2,v3]=[0.9.0.1.0],
[0.9.0,0.1]
etc..
When I run it on 0-1, the inner loop skips the 0.9-1 count. But when I run it on 0-10, it goes smoothly. So I just loop it on 0-10, then divide it by 10 to collect the needed values, then multiply it back by 10 to continue the loop.

Consider dividing only at the very end, after all the looping when your data array is complete. Your constraint now is v1+v2+v3=100. It is much better to find all these combinations with integers than with floats, integers don't have rounding errors.

(EDITED:  a simpler solution has been appended to the end of this answer.)
for a non looping version of solving this problem, you can use broadcasting and indexing operations to get the answer as well:
first, create your three vectors in different dimensions (using 0:1:10 instead of 0:0.1:1 so that we're only working with integer values as @CrisLuengo suggested in the comments above):
>> v1 = 0:10
v1 =

    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10

>> v2 = [0:10].'
v2 =

    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
   10

>> v3 = reshape(0:10,1,1,11)
v3 =

ans(:,:,1) = 0
ans(:,:,2) = 1
ans(:,:,3) = 2
ans(:,:,4) = 3
ans(:,:,5) = 4
ans(:,:,6) = 5
ans(:,:,7) = 6
ans(:,:,8) = 7
ans(:,:,9) = 8
ans(:,:,10) = 9
ans(:,:,11) = 10

Then find all summations using automatic expansion to 3 dimensions via broadcasting:
>> v4 = v1+v2+v3
v4 =

ans(:,:,1) =

    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17
    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20

ans(:,:,2) =

    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17
    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21

ans(:,:,3) =

    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17
    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21
   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22

ans(:,:,4) =

    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17
    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21
   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22
   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23

ans(:,:,5) =

    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17
    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21
   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22
   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23
   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24

ans(:,:,6) =

    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17
    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21
   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22
   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23
   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24
   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25

ans(:,:,7) =

    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17
    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21
   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22
   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23
   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24
   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25
   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26

ans(:,:,8) =

    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17
    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21
   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22
   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23
   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24
   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25
   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27

ans(:,:,9) =

    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18
    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21
   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22
   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23
   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24
   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25
   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27
   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28

ans(:,:,10) =

    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21
   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22
   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23
   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24
   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25
   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27
   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28
   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29

ans(:,:,11) =

   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20
   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21
   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22
   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23
   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24
   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25
   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26
   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27
   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28
   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29
   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30

Then find all locations where v4 = 10:
>> idx = find(v4==10)
idx =

     11
     21
     31
     41
     51
     61
     71
     81
     91
    101
    111
    131
    141
    151
    161
    171
    181
    191
    201
    211
    221
    251
    261
    271
    281
    291
    301
    311
    321
    331
    371
    381
    391
    401
    411
    421
    431
    441
    491
    501
    511
    521
    531
    541
    551
    611
    621
    631
    641
    651
    661
    731
    741
    751
    761
    771
    851
    861
    871
    881
    971
    981
    991
   1091
   1101
   1211

these are linear indices of locations in v4.  since those positions correspond to our values of v1, v2, and v3, we can convert to subscript location to get their values:
>> [x,y,z] = ind2sub([11,11,11], idx)
x =

   11
   10
    9
    8
    7
    6
    5
    4
    3
    2
    1
   10
    9
    8
    7
    6
    5
    4
    3
    2
    1
    9
    8
    7
    6
    5
    4
    3
    2
    1
    8
    7
    6
    5
    4
    3
    2
    1
    7
    6
    5
    4
    3
    2
    1
    6
    5
    4
    3
    2
    1
    5
    4
    3
    2
    1
    4
    3
    2
    1
    3
    2
    1
    2
    1
    1

y =

    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
   10
   11
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
   10
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    1
    2
    3
    4
    1
    2
    3
    1
    2
    1

z =

    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    2
    2
    2
    2
    2
    2
    2
    2
    2
    2
    3
    3
    3
    3
    3
    3
    3
    3
    3
    4
    4
    4
    4
    4
    4
    4
    4
    5
    5
    5
    5
    5
    5
    5
    6
    6
    6
    6
    6
    6
    7
    7
    7
    7
    7
    8
    8
    8
    8
    9
    9
    9
   10
   10
   11

Last, remembering that our numbers go from 0:10 while indices go from 1:11, and we actually wanted 0:0.1:1, we concatenate them into a single array, shift by one, then divide by 10:
>> xyz = ([x, y, z] - 1)/10
xyz =

   1.0000        0        0
   0.9000   0.1000        0
   0.8000   0.2000        0
   0.7000   0.3000        0
   0.6000   0.4000        0
   0.5000   0.5000        0
   0.4000   0.6000        0
   0.3000   0.7000        0
   0.2000   0.8000        0
   0.1000   0.9000        0
        0   1.0000        0
   0.9000        0   0.1000
   0.8000   0.1000   0.1000
   0.7000   0.2000   0.1000
   0.6000   0.3000   0.1000
   0.5000   0.4000   0.1000
   0.4000   0.5000   0.1000
   0.3000   0.6000   0.1000
   0.2000   0.7000   0.1000
   0.1000   0.8000   0.1000
        0   0.9000   0.1000
   0.8000        0   0.2000
   0.7000   0.1000   0.2000
   0.6000   0.2000   0.2000
   0.5000   0.3000   0.2000
   0.4000   0.4000   0.2000
   0.3000   0.5000   0.2000
   0.2000   0.6000   0.2000
   0.1000   0.7000   0.2000
        0   0.8000   0.2000
   0.7000        0   0.3000
   0.6000   0.1000   0.3000
   0.5000   0.2000   0.3000
   0.4000   0.3000   0.3000
   0.3000   0.4000   0.3000
   0.2000   0.5000   0.3000
   0.1000   0.6000   0.3000
        0   0.7000   0.3000
   0.6000        0   0.4000
   0.5000   0.1000   0.4000
   0.4000   0.2000   0.4000
   0.3000   0.3000   0.4000
   0.2000   0.4000   0.4000
   0.1000   0.5000   0.4000
        0   0.6000   0.4000
   0.5000        0   0.5000
   0.4000   0.1000   0.5000
   0.3000   0.2000   0.5000
   0.2000   0.3000   0.5000
   0.1000   0.4000   0.5000
        0   0.5000   0.5000
   0.4000        0   0.6000
   0.3000   0.1000   0.6000
   0.2000   0.2000   0.6000
   0.1000   0.3000   0.6000
        0   0.4000   0.6000
   0.3000        0   0.7000
   0.2000   0.1000   0.7000
   0.1000   0.2000   0.7000
        0   0.3000   0.7000
   0.2000        0   0.8000
   0.1000   0.1000   0.8000
        0   0.2000   0.8000
   0.1000        0   0.9000
        0   0.1000   0.9000
        0        0   1.0000

That should be every combination. If you want you can use sortrows to sort by a particular column.
In summary, the short script to solve the problem (that could be shortened a bit more by removing some of the intermediate variables) is:
v1 = 0:10;
v2 = v1.';
v3 = reshape (v1, 1,1,11);
v4 = v1 + v2 + v3;
idx = find (v4 == 10);
[x, y, z] = ind2sub ([11,11,11], idx);
xyz = ([x,y,z] - 1) / 10;

And you can use sum (xyz, 2) to verify every row sums to 1.
EDIT:
another good @CrisLuengo suggestion, you can reduce amount of data sifted by just using find for v1+v2<=10, and then calculate v3.  This also lets you just use the two-output form of find and avoid the ind2sub call. it reduces the script to:
v1 = 0:10; 
v2 = v1.';
[x,y] = find (v1+v2 <= 10);
xyz = [x-1, y-1, 12-x-y] / 10;


This is nice, but I would find v3 by computing it from v1 and v2. That should save you a ton of memory.

good point.  edited.
